# Riverpod UI not updating properly

Tags: flutter, state-management, riverpod

I have a switch widget when I slide it for example from **OFF** > **ON** it goes  **ON** > **OFF** > **ON** on the UI. Same thing happens with **ON** > **OFF** example.

Why is this behavior? is it the way I'm using the provider? I've tried declaring boolean value for the switch at the top and use it but still same result.

#### Provider

```
final profileProvider = StateNotifierProvider<ProfileUserNotifier, AsyncValue<ProfileUser>>((ref) {
  return ProfileUserNotifier(ref.read);
});
```

#### State notifier

```
class ProfileUserNotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<ProfileUser>> {
  ProfileUserNotifier(
    this.read, [
    AsyncValue<ProfileUser>? profileUser,
  ]) : super(profileUser ?? const AsyncValue.loading()) {
    _getProfileUser();
  }

  final Reader read;

  Future<void> _getProfileUser() async {
     state = AsyncValue.loading();
      final profile = await read(apiServiceProvider)!.getProfile();
      state = AsyncValue.data(profile!);
  }

 refresh(ProfileUser profile) {
      state = AsyncValue.loading();
      state = AsyncValue.data(profile);
  }
}
```

#### Screen

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Account Settings'),
      ),
      body: Consumer(builder: (context, ref, child) {
        var profile = ref.watch(profileProvider);

        return profile.when(
          loading: () => Container(
              child: Scaffold(
                  body: Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator()))),
          error: (err, stack) => Text('Error $err'),
          data: (profile) => SwitchListTile(
            value: profile.visible!,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              var updatedProfile = profile.copyWith(visible: value);
              ref.read(apiServiceProvider)!.updateUser(updatedProfile).then(
                  (profileUser) => {
                        ref.read(profileProvider.notifier).refresh(profileUser)
                      });
            },
            title: new Text(
              'Visible',
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

#### Model

```
@immutable
class ProfileUser {
  ProfileUser({this.id, this.username, this.visible});

  final int? id;
  final String? username;
  final bool? visible;

  ProfileUser copyWith({int? id, String? username, bool? visible}) {
    return ProfileUser(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      username: username ?? this.username,
      visible: visible ?? this.visible,
    );
  }
}
```

[image: gif]

Comment: At `refresh` method, print `profile.visible` and see if the value printed is always right.

Comment: Yes, it prints the right value

Comment: Hmm...Could add a gif to show the UI behaviour?

Comment: Gif animation added now

Comment: Can you share your code for `apiServiceProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by changing the order of calls, so update the state then call the api instead of calling the api then updating the state.

The only problem now is that if the api update fails there's no way to update the UI.